# Can UTF-8 hold the same data that UTF-16 can hold

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

Using Java I'm persisting multilingual text to a file in a UTF-16 format. To save disk space I want to switch to use UTF-8.
**Can UTF-8 express the same range of character sets that UTF-16 can?**

This will allow me to avoid regression or extensive testing in different human languages.
Most of my content is in English so I expect to save disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can. [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) are just different ways to translate Unicode characters to bytes and vice versa.

Both encodings can encode all possible Unicode characters.

From the links (Wikipedia):

> **UTF-8** (U from Universal Character Set + Transformation Format—8-bit) is a character encoding capable of encoding all possible characters (called code points) in Unicode. ... UTF-8 encodes each of the 1,112,064 valid code points in the Unicode code space (1,114,112 code points minus 2,048 surrogate code points) using one to four 8-bit bytes (a group of 8 bits is known as an octet in the Unicode Standard).
>
> **UTF-16** (16-bit Unicode Transformation Format) is a character encoding capable of encoding all 1,112,064 possible characters in Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 and UTF-16 can represent all valid Unicode-codepoints.

UTF-8 can also represent invalid UTF-16 sequences (with relaxed validation).
The reverse does not hold.